# Jenkins Pipeline loop ends unexpectedly

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to verify that all my web applications in one tomcat are running after execution of Jenkins pipeline.

I am verifing more than one url so I want to do that in for loop.
It ends on first url in collection.

Here is my code

```
@NonCPS
def verifyServices(list) {
    echo "Services: "+list.size()
    def result = true
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
        if(result) {
            result = testUrl(list[i])
        }
    }
    return result
}

def verify = []
verify.add("http://example.com:8082")
verify.add("http://example.com:8082/rest/version")
verify.add("http://example.com:8082/mobile/version")
verifyServices(verify)
```

And testUrl function

```
def call(urlString) {
    echo "Testing ${urlString}"
    def url = new URL(urlString)
    def HttpURLConnection connection = url.openConnection()
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET")
    connection.setDoInput(true)

    try {
        connection.connect()
        def code = connection.getResponseCode()
        echo "Response code ${code}"
        return code == 200
    } finally {
        connection.disconnect()
    }
}
```

Here is my log

```
Proceeding
[Pipeline] echo
Services: 3
[Pipeline] echo
Testing http://example.com:8082
[Pipeline] echo
Response code 200
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
```

When I remove call to `testUrl` function in `verifyServices` it iterates over all of them.

Am I doing something wrong? Or for loops are just broken?

Comment: For loops aren't broken

Comment: Great. So what I am doing wrong? When I use a function (or just sh "echo test"  inside for loop it stops iterating...

Comment: The supposed `testUrl` function is called `call`? You sure the call does not bail out with an exception, or why is there a _finally_ block?

Comment: It's Jenkins pipeline thing ( https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-global-lib-plugin/blob/master/README.md ). Finally is there to close the connection, it's doing the same thing even if I call the Jenkins pipeline bash function (but not the echo function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow the `@NonCPS` annotation is messing with your methods calls. Remove it and you will be just fine. Plus I don't think you need it in the first place, your code doesn't seem to introduce any serializable issue `@NonCPS` annotation would fix...

You can read more on [CPS technical design](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-plugin/blob/master/README.md#technical-design) or tutorial recommendations on [how to serializable variables](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md#serializing-local-variables).

Comment: Thank you this works, I do not know why used that annotation.